# Hide attribute definition if the value is empty in Jinja?

Tags: jinja2

```
<vcpu placement='{{cpu.placement}}' cpuset='{{cpu.cpuset}}' current={{cpu.current}}>{{ cpu['maximum'] }}</vcpu>
```

Giving that we have 3 possible attributes and any of them can be empty.

Is there a neat way to hide the attribute definition if the value is empty? Let's say if `cpu.placement` is empty, the line `placement=''` shouldn't be there in the XML definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the attribute definition inside an `if`-block:

```
<vcpu 
  {% if cpu.placement %}placement='{{cpu.placement}}'{% endif %}
  {% if cpu.cpuset %}cpuset='{{cpu.cpuset}}'{% endif %}
  {% if cpu.current %}current={{cpu.current}}>{{ cpu['maximum'] }}{% endif %}
</vcpu>
```

See the [list of builtin tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) in you need more complicated test for a variable.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. In the end I pre-processed the data making cpu.placement returns "placement='static'". This way we don't have to check anymore.